# Run a COUNTIF in R for specified columns

Tags: r, countif

I need to create a 'new' column and run the equivalent of a COUNTIF function over specified columns (i.e. the 'Output' columns). For example I need to count if those columns contain a 3 or a 4.

Example data with desired column on the right

```
x  Output.1  Output.2  Output.3  Output.4  Output.5  y  new
1  3         3         NA        NA        NA        2  2
1  4         4         3         3         NA        2  4
1  3         3         3         3         3         2  5
1  2         2         4         4         4         2  3
```

I have tried using rowSums (after a bit of a search) for example:

```
df$new <- rowSums(df[c('Output.1', 'Output.2', 'Output.3', 'Output.4', 'Output.5')] == 3)
```

and using `grep` to isolate the columns

```
df[, new:= rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = grep("Output.", names(df))]
```

although the latter sums the values - I need a count of instances and I can't figure out how to gt the condition of == 3 in there.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` for this:

```
df$new <- apply(df[, grep("Output.", names(df))], MARGIN = 1, 
                function(x) sum(x %in% c(3, 4), na.rm = T))

df 
#   x Output.1 Output.2 Output.3 Output.4 Output.5 y new
# 1 1        3        3       NA       NA       NA 2   2
# 2 1        4        4        3        3       NA 2   4
# 3 1        3        3        3        3        3 2   5
# 4 1        2        2        4        4        4 2   3
```

Comment: Thanks kath - this works perfectly with that data frame - when I use it on a larger data frame with more columns I get this error -           
 Error in apply(Activity_final[, grep("Output.", names(Activity_final))],  : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length _____                                            
 would you have any idea why (is it for example that I have some factors within those extra columns?)

Comment: Check if `Activity_final[, grep("Output.", names(Activity_final))]` returns a nonempty dataframe. If not you have to adjust the `"Output."` to the columns you want to work with.

Comment: It returns `3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11` so not empty. The columns in this case would always be the `"Output"` cols in any case.